# Not able to signup a new developer environment (DE)

Tags: developer-edition

Just signed up for a new Developer Environment (DE) at https://developer.salesforce.com/signup

As usual, fill out the sign up form and click the "Sign me Up" button.

However, this time, after clicking the signup button, the page stops at the same page (signup) and doesn't receive any email for user activation.

Then, I waited for several hours, still no email.

I've also tried different email addresses and the results are all the same.

Is there any changes about developer environment signup?

Comment: I am experiencing  the same issue. I am working with internal Engineering team on it. Will let you know updates on it.

Comment: The relevant Salesforce product team is working on the fix and I will let you know as I hear back on an ETA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was some issue in product side and it is resolved now .
You will be able to sign up to developer edition org with out any issues.

Thanks for reporting the issue.

Comment: I'm still facing the issue here